# Is the subtraction of two summations with sequential stopping points equal to the typical element?

Tags: summation

If I have two summations, $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^2$ and I subtract the summation with the larger stopping point from the one with the smaller stopping point, like so

$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^2 - \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2$

will the result be $(n+1)^2$? If not, why?

Comment: Yes, it will. Can you say a little about why you're unsure?

Comment: @Chris Because I'm using that for a proof for a discrete math class and it seemed a bit cheap to be able to use that. Maybe there's another mistake I'm not catching, or it's easier than I thought lol

Comment: How do you even define $\sum_{k=1}^n$ if not by recursion and this very property? (I mean formally, that is without using "$\ldots$" anywhere)

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen good point! I didn't think of that